# Laptop from previous job was resold, still with my iCloud on it. What happens when I remove the laptop from Find My Iphone? Best way to proceed?

Tags: mac, laptop, macbook, icloud

I got an email from a stranger who said they bought a laptop on Ebay from Techrecommerce recycling company, and that it is locked under my iCloud account.

It appears to be the my laptop from a previous job. Seems like the laptop just sat on a shelf for a couple of years, and then was re-sold. (I still need to verify serial numbers and whatnot wherever appropriate).

This person is requesting me to remotely remove the laptop from Find My Mac so they can access the hardware.

I'm specifically wondering:

- What exactly will happen when I remove this laptop from "Find My Mac"?
- Is there an additional (or different) precaution I could take remotely? Should I suggest them to revert/reinstall the OS or something instead?
- Would removing the laptop from "Find My Mac" remove any of my data from the laptop? (not sure what is on there. I had some miscellaneous personal files and was logged into some notes applications, etc.)

  - (I also see [documentation to "Remotely erase a device" here](https://support.apple.com/guide/findmy-mac/erase-a-device-fmmbe7bb71f4/2.0/mac/11.0#fmmbf71751e1) )

I want to make sure that I do the correct settings, and also to make sure that I'm not responding to a weird scam or something. If anyone has experience in these matters, I'd appreciate hearing what you know, thank you :)

Comment: I can’t imagine what the scam is. I would just remove the laptop from your iCloud.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - scam or no scam, why leave potentially sensitive data on there when there's a wipe button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd run the erase procedure from iCloud.

That will do both jobs - clean the Mac down ready for the next user & also remove from Find My.*
Just removing from Find My will leave your existing install & documents in place, whilst unlocking it for the new user. It will still have your account in place - which they wouldn't know the password for, but it's not impossible to get round that. However, it may also have FileVault enabled, which would effectively prevent them from using it at all.

Presuming the new owner has bought this in good faith, let him know what you're doing so he'll be aware he'll end up with a released, but clean Mac.
In case he thought he'd "won" any apps already installed, that won't be the case. They belong to your ID too, including, in effect, the OS itself - so starting from a clean install would be the way to go anyway.

*I've never had to do this, so I don't know if it just removes sensitive information or if it fully re-installs from scratch. iOS devices return to 'just bought/first run' status, but I'm not sure for Macs.

Comment: thank you! i started the "erase" procedure, waiting for the new owner to connect it online. keeping an eye out, i case i need to do that extra release step after the process is over.